Convert pair of parametric trig equations to $y=f(x)$ form
My apologies if this already has an answer, I've spent some time looking but haven't found anything that (to me) looked directly applicable.
I have a set of parametric equations describing a periodic curve on an interval, say, $0\le t\le 4\pi$:
$$
x=t+\sin{(t)}\\
y=-\cos{(t)}
$$
This curve looks like a function, so I feel like I ought to be able to come up with a Cartesian form $y=f(x)$ for which each (x,y) coordinate pair would be identical to the corresponding parametric coordinate pair.
I've tried solving and substituting, but I only know how to solve the $y$ parametric for $t$:
$$y=-\cos{(t)}$$
becomes
$$
t=\arccos{(-y)}$$
And so I treat can $y$ as the independent variable and do:
$$
x=\arccos{(-y)} + \sin{(\arccos{(-y)})}
$$
with $y$ defined only over the interval $-1\le y \le 1$ which limits me to a single half of one wavelength, and repeated concatenating of this is not trivial because the interval between each successive x-value is not the same.  I don't know how to solve the $x$ parametric, maybe someone who is a whiz with trig identities can offer a path.
I can use the x and y parametric values to create an interpolation programatically, but this is cumbersome and problematic for reasons beyond scope, etc.
Here's a plot (code at the bottom, in Python) of a parametric and interpolated version of this curve:
parametric equations: x=a+sin(a); y=-cos(t); 0<t<4pi
My motivation is to be able to treat multiple wavelengths/amplitudes/phases as discretized waveforms to be manipulated together, with identical sample rate, syncronous sampling, etc. in simulating various physical effects (sample-wise addition, etc.).  Also, not being able to figure this out bugs me.  I would think this would be a simple additional term, as in $y=-cos{(x + [some\ expression])}$ over $x$ in some interval, but I can't come up with this additional expression.  Maybe this is a case requiring implicitization as mentioned here?
Python code I used for the plot:
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator as AML
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')



cyc = 3.0
n_per_cyc = 20


def xy_from_a(a):
    x = a + np.sin(a)
    y = -np.cos(a)
    return x, y

def interp_param_to_xy(a, x, y):
    interpolator = interp1d(x, y)
    x_interpolated = np.array(a)
    y_interpolated = interpolator(x_interpolated)
    return x_interpolated, y_interpolated

def plot(
        xmin=None, xmax=None, ymin=None, ymax=None,
        xunits=None, yunits=None,
        title=None, square=True,
        ):
    plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [18, 4]
    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_xlabel('x (radians)', fontsize=16)
    ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=16)

    ax.plot(x_neg_cos, y_neg_cos,
        label='neg_cos', color='#000000',
        linestyle=':',
        marker='.', markersize=5.0,
        linewidth=0.5)
    ax.plot(x_parametric, y_parametric,
        label='parametric', color='#009f00',
        linestyle='-',
        marker='.', markersize=8.0,
        linewidth=1.0)
    ax.plot(x_interpolated, y_interpolated,
        label='interpolated', color='#ff0000',
        linestyle=':',
        marker='.', markersize=5.0,
        linewidth=1.0)

    plt.legend(loc='best')
    minorLocator1X = AML()
    minorLocator1Y = AML()
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator1X)
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator1Y)
    ax.tick_params(which='major', width=2, length=7)
    ax.tick_params(which='minor', width=2, length=4)
    ax.grid(visible=True, which='major', color='gray', linestyle='-')
    ax.grid(visible=True, which='minor', color='gray', linestyle=':')

    if title is not None:
        plt.title(title, fontsize=20)

    if xunits is not None:
        ax.set_xlabel(xunits, fontsize=16)
    if yunits is not None:
        ax.set_ylabel(yunits, fontsize=16)

    if xmin is not None:
        ax.axis(xmin=xmin)
    if xmax is not None:
        ax.axis(xmax=xmax)
    if ymin is not None:
        ax.axis(ymin=ymin)
    if ymax is not None:
        ax.axis(ymax=ymax)

    if square:
        ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

    plt.tight_layout()

    plt.show()



print('x = θ + sin(θ)')
print('y = -cos(θ)')



n = int(round(n_per_cyc * cyc, 0))
t = np.linspace(0.0, 2.0 * np.pi * cyc, num=n + 1, endpoint=True)

x_neg_cos = t[:n]
y_neg_cos = -np.cos(x_neg_cos)

x_parametric, y_parametric = xy_from_a(t)

t = t[:n]

x_interpolated, y_interpolated = interp_param_to_xy(t, x_parametric, y_parametric)

x_parametric = x_parametric[:n]
y_parametric = y_parametric[:n]



plot(
    xmin=0.0,
    xmax=np.pi /  2.0 * 8.0,
    square=True,
)

EDIT:
Thanks @Gwen, with the help of your comment/answer I succeeded in finding several trig identities that let me follow you to your answer:
$$y=-\cos(x\pm\sqrt{1-y^2})$$
It may be possible, using further trig identities or some other means, to solve for y, but if so, I can't figure it out.  So, I solved for x, which gives me:
$$x=\arccos(-y)\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$$
But of course this, even treated piecewise, leaves me with the same problem as before, in that x is not the independent variable.  (Also, in a programmatic context like Python, x values for both halves come out positive because of how arccos is defined to output in [0, $\pi$].)
Is there a way to solve for y, or some other way to rearrange this so that, whether piecewise or not, y is calculated from x, enabling me to programmatically assign x (piecewise if necessary) over whatever domain and granularity I need?

You can simplify$$\sin(\arccos(-y))=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+\arcsin y\right)=\cos(\arcsin y) = \sqrt{1-y^2}$$but the end result is a transcendental equation in $y$.

Sadly this is still defined within that [-1,1] range. @user170231 I have a question regarding inv trigo indetities. Why isn't $$\cos(\arcsin y)= ±\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

@Gwen $\arcsin y\in\left[-\pi/2,\pi/2\right]\implies\cos(\arcsin y)\ge0$

$$x^2+y^2=t^2+1+2t\sin t=1+2tx-t^2$$
$$\implies y^2=1-(x-t)^2\implies t=x\mp\sqrt{1-y^2}$$
So
$$y=-\cos\bigg(x\mp \sqrt{1-y^2}\bigg)$$
For this we need a piecewise function.
$$y=\begin{cases}
\cos(x+\sqrt{1-y^2}) & (2n-1)π≤x≤2nπ\\
\cos(x-\sqrt{1-y^2}) & 2nπ≤x≤(2n+1)π\\
\end{cases}\\n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
You can check this graph in desmos. This wriggles through both the functions like a worm, if you set $n$ as rational numbers.

OK @Gwen, I think I see how this works, this is good.  I can deal with piecewise.  Unfortunately, for my purposes, I'm using discrete waveforms, so I have a list of values for x to plug into the equations.  So, I need to solve for y.  I can easily solve for x in the above, and calculate x as a function of y, but then the x values are not evenly spaced, of course.  So I'm still a little stuck...  But thanks!

The full form of this very simple model includes terms for amplitude and wavelength ($\lambda$):
$x=(\lambda t/2\pi) + (\sin(t)*amplitude)$ and $y=-\cos(\lambda t/2\pi)$
